# How can I resize an UIView by code?

Tags: ios, swift

For Example:

I can get the height of `UIImageView(identifier:ImgView)` by the top and bottom constraints and I want to let its width be (4/3 x height).

How can I do it?

I have ever tried doing it by this sentence:

```
ImgView.frame.width = ImgView.frame.height * 4.0 / 3.0
```

But it didn't work with an error said:

```
it can't assign to ImgView.frame.width
```

So, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CGRect frame = ImgView.frame;
frame.size.width = frame.size.height * 4/3;
ImgView.frame = frame;
```

---

Or a one-liner:

```
ImgView.frame = CGRectMake(ImgView.frame.origin.x,
                           ImgView.frame.origin.y,
                           ImgView.frame.size.height * 4/3,
                           ImgView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: This should work if you're doing it in code, but if you want a better solution, go with [@Poql's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31365841/2177402) using **Aspect Ratio** constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Use a ratio constraint. Easy peasy.

[image]